# Can I chain a .then() after a forEach() array helper?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, foreach, callback

Can I do something like this?

```
const array = ["foo", "bar", "hello", "etc"];

array.forEach(item => process(item)).then(() => {
    //run after forEach is done processing the whole array
});
```

Comment: Hi Jamil, AFAIK, you can do that only if process returns a promise.

Comment: If `process(item)` is returning promise then `Promise.all` can help you there.

Comment: not natively, but bluebird promises can do this: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html

Comment: I'm not really sure why you'd want to? `Array.forEach` is a synchronous method (that's "a synchronous", not "an asynchronous"). It will run completely before anything after it is run. The point of promises/.then is to allow an asynchronous function to continue running while the rest of the code also continues. As Prakash Sharma said, if the `process` method is returning a promise, you'll want to add each returned promise to an array and use `Promise.all` to attach a `.then` callback for when they're all complete.

Comment: It would help people give good answers it you told us what `process(item)` did/returned.

Answer (score 2):

No. then is used for handling promises.
forEach is synchronous so you should probably save the processed items in a new array and then do the post processing logic right after.

Answer (score 2):

```
const values = ["foo", "bar", "hello", "etc"];
Promise.all(values.map(process)).then((results)=>{
    //run after all promises are resolved
    console.log(results instanceof Array); // prints true
});
```

You can use a `Promise.all()` to resolve an array of promises, and use `values.map(process)` to execute the `process()` function for each array item as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to execute some steps after forEach, then you can achieve it with sequential steps as (forEach is sync)

Execution Line 1

```
const array = ["foo", "bar", "hello", "etc"];
```

Execution Line 2

```
array.forEach(item => process(item))
```

Execution Line 3

```
//Write your steps here to do after array.forEach
```